# when we call function, is argument parenthesis () is needed if no argument pass like func; vs func();

Tags: c++, class, static

The static function `getROI` always returns `1` and also causes a warning :

> the address of 'static float Account::getROI()' will never be NULL

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Account
{
private:
    int account_no;
    int balance;
    static float ROI;
public:
    void setBalance(int x){balance=x;}
    int getBalance(){return balance;}
    void setAccountNo(int y){account_no=y;}
    int getAccountNo(){return account_no;}
    static void setROI(float z){ROI=z;}
    static float getROI(){return ROI;}

};
float Account::ROI =0;
int main()
{
    cout << "STATIC" << endl;
    Account obj;
    obj.setAccountNo(3435647);
    obj.setBalance(1000000);
    obj.setROI(4.9);
    cout<<"Account No : "<<obj.getAccountNo()<<endl;
    cout<<"Balance    = "<<obj.getBalance()<<endl;
    cout<<"Rate of int= "<<obj.getROI;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as typo. `obj.getROI` -> `obj.getROI()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says the *address* will never be zero.

Which is true ... if the address were zero, reading it would be de-referencing a null pointer.

So you think you're looking at the data, but you're really looking at a pointer to the data, and (I presume) comparing that address to zero.

Comment: I put that there before I read the code, I can be more specific now.

You forgot the parens, so you were taking the address of the function, not calling it.

Answer (score 1):

You want `obj.getROI()`, not `obj.getROI`